# Content Panel Switcher & SwipeJS

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use a content panel switcher (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-content-panel-switcher/) and Swipejs (http://swipejs.com/) together. I'm able to get both of these to work independently but when I put the swipejs code within one of the content panels the code breaks. I'm assuming there must be a conflict with jQuery but I'm fairly new to jQuery and I'm stuck on what to do to debug the issue. Below is my current code. Thanks for any help.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.content-panel-switcher.js'></script>  
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    jcps.fader(300, '#switcher-panel', '.set1');
    jcps.slider(500, '#switcher-panel2', '.set2');
});
</script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="block mid margin_auto">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="nav_buttons"> 
            <a id="set1panel1" class="switcher set1">Home</a> 
            <a id="set1panel2" class="switcher set1">Photography</a> 
            <a id="set1panel3" class="switcher set1">Design</a> 
        </div> 
    </div>
        <div id="switcher-panel"></div>

        <!-- Dummy Data -->
        <div id="set1panel1-content" class="switcher-content set1 show">
            <h2>Set 1 Panel 1</h2>
            Set 1 Panel 1 content goes here.....
            <div id='mySwipe' style='max-width:500px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
                <div class='swipe-wrap'>
                    <div><b>0</b></div>
                    <div><b>1</b></div>
                    <div><b>2</b></div>
                    <div><b>3</b></div>
                    <div><b>4</b></div>
                    <div><b>5</b></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>
              <button onclick='mySwipe.prev()'>prev</button> 
              <button onclick='mySwipe.next()'>next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="set1panel2-content" class="switcher-content set1">
        <h2>Set 1 Panel 2</h2>
            Set 1 Panel 2 content goes here.....
        </div>
        <div id="set1panel3-content" class="switcher-content set1">
        <h2>Set 1 Panel 3</h2>
            Set 1 Panel 3 content goes here.....
        </div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="block mid margin_auto">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="nav_buttons"> 
            <a id="set2panel1" class="switcher set2">Experience</a> 
            <a id="set2panel2" class="switcher set2">Sports</a> 
            <a id="set2panel3" class="switcher set2">Hobbies</a> 
        </div> 
    </div>
        <div id="switcher-panel2"></div>

        <!-- Dummy Data -->
        <div id="set2panel1-content" class="switcher-content set2 show">
        <h2>Set 2 Panel 1</h2>
        Set 2 Panel 1 content goes here.....
            <div id='mySwipe2' style='max-width:500px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
                <div class='swipe-wrap'>
                    <div><b>A</b></div>
                    <div><b>B</b></div>
                    <div><b>C</b></div>
                    <div><b>D</b></div>
                    <div><b>E</b></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>
              <button onclick='mySwipe.prev()'>prev</button> 
              <button onclick='mySwipe.next()'>next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="set2panel2-content" class="switcher-content set2">
        <h2>Set 2 Panel 2</h2>
        Set 2 Panel 2 content goes here.....
        </div>
        <div id="set2panel3-content" class="switcher-content set2">
        <h2>Set 2 Panel 3</h2>
        Set 2 Panel 3 content goes here.....
        </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='js/swipe.js'></script>
<script>
// pure JS
var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
  startSlide: 0,
  // auto: 3000,
  // continuous: true,
  // disableScroll: true,
  // stopPropagation: true,
  // callback: function(index, element) {},
  // transitionEnd: function(index, element) {}
});
// with jQuery
// window.mySwipe = $('#mySwipe').Swipe().data('Swipe');
</script>
<script>
// pure JS
var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe2');
window.mySwipe2 = Swipe(elem, {
  startSlide: 0,
  // auto: 3000,
  // continuous: true,
  // disableScroll: true,
  // stopPropagation: true,
  // callback: function(index, element) {},
  // transitionEnd: function(index, element) {}
});
// with jQuery
// window.mySwipe = $('#mySwipe').Swipe().data('Swipe');
</script>
```

Comment: It would help a lot of you could post any exception or error messages you are receiving when you say "the code breaks".

Comment: I don't see an actual error message but the all of the SwipeJS functionality does not work. I'll post a screenshot of what I see when the code is rendered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict is between the techniques of the two plugins rather than anything in jquery.

Two big problems:

1) The elements div#mySwipe(2) need to be visible on the page when their setup() function is called. Swipe needs this so it can calculate the width of the slides. setup() is called when swipe starts, it is also fired on page resizes and in some browsers when you switch browser tabs. You can also call it yourself mySwipe.setup()

The css of content-panel, hides everything within .switcher-content. Both swipe div's are in such a class.

You can fix this by initializing swipe after content-panel, this will be a short term fix though, due to problem two.

2) content-panel seems to work by having a display div, and copying the content from the switcher-content divs as needed. If you initialize swipe after content-panel you will in fact initialize swipe on the panels copy, once you navigate away to a different panel this copy will be lost and when you navigate back you will once again have a broken swipe.

What you need to happen is:

1. when swipe calls setup initially it needs to be in a visible div
2. modify swipe.js so that page resize events call a wrapper function that checks if the swipe div is visible, if not, do nothing.
3. ideally call setup everytime the swipe panel is made visible

These three task require changing the code of your chosen plugins.

To debug the issues I recommend the various browser dev tools. Using the inspect element tools lets you see the html the plugins are generating, ie you'll see swipe is setting width to 0 instead of 3000 when it is a hidden div. Javascript debugging lets you break in the setup method of the swipe code and see why.